xoyplot polar The lower half circle does not occupy space
I want a polar diagram of a semicircle, and I have implemented it, but the lower semicircle still takes up space. What should I do？thank u I hope the lower half circle doesn't take up space
The interface is adaptive, so I don't want to use margin or padding
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/v8eCfKKo.png) [enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/3Kys3yLl.png) [enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/e8QcNEEv.png)

Please don't post your code an images but rather text.  If we need to copy and paste you code then it is not possible from an image.
